# C# Bringing the value twice error

Tags: c#, constructor

```
public MenClothing(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtUsername.Text = text;
}
```

Hello so when we tried to carry a value from form1 > form2(label) > form3(textbox)  with added this below it gives a error:

```
Error System.InvalidOperationException: The connectionString Property has not been initialized at System.Data.OleDbConnection.PermissionDemand .
```

Update:After adding that below, it shows this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqBUP.png)

```
public partial class MenClothing : Form
{
    OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();

    public MenClothing(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtUsername.Text = text;
    }

    public MenClothing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C: \Users\Teronkee\Desktop\OFFICAL STAC\OFFICAL STAC\StacProductions\DatabaseSaveItem.accdb";


    }

    private int upperCase(string pass)
    {
        int num = 0;
        foreach (char ch in pass)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(ch))
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

    private void btnlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 Return = new Form2(txtUsername.Text);
        Return.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void MenClothing_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            connect.Open();

            connect.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ItemUrl.Text;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ItemUrl.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connect;
                command.CommandText = "insert into RegisterItem([Name], [Url],[Description], [Price]) values('" + ItemName.Text + "','" + ItemUrl.Text + "','" + ItemDescription.Text + "','" + ItemPrice.Text + "')";


                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
                connect.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
                connect.Close();
            }

            string str = ItemUrl.Text;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = str;
            //string str = textBox1.Text;
            // Image img = Image.FromFile(str);
            // pictureBox1.Image = img;

            txtUsername = txtID1;
            ItemName = txtName1;
            ItemDescription = txtDescription1;
            ItemPrice = txtPrice1;

            ItemName.Text = "";
            ItemDescription.Text = "";
            ItemPrice.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == txtID1.Text)
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the connection string in the constructor accepting a string.
Change it like so:

```
public MenClothing(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtUsername.Text = text;
    connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C: \Users\Teronkee\Desktop\OFFICAL STAC\OFFICAL STAC\StacProductions\DatabaseSaveItem.accdb";
}
```

or better, to avoid code duplication, move the line setting the connectionstring to its own function and call it from both constructors

Comment: What do u mean by call it both constructors? cause it has no problem going form1(textbox)>form2(label)

Comment: Your form has two constructors: public MenClothing(string text) and public MenClothing(). My guess is that you are creating the form with the public MenClothing(string text) constructor when you are seeing the error

Comment: yeah , i created that as i have to transfer value , but it doesn't seem to work after going from form1>form2>form3(erorr starts) http://i.stack.imgur.com/pqBUP.png

Comment: Yup , it's cause of that , that is causing the error , and i couldnt findany ways to fix it regarding that cause i have to transfer data from form1(textbox) > form2(label) > form3 (textbox) as i'm showing the username

Comment: I think it's because of the space between c: and the rest of the path, try removing that space, like so: Data Source=C:\Users\Teronkee\Desktop\OFFICAL STAC\OFFICAL STAC\StacProductions\DatabaseSaveItem.accdb

Comment: Is it i must add both connection strings?